# More efficient movements editing python files in vim

Tags: python, vim, editing

Given a python file with the following repeated endlessly:

```
def myFunction(a, b, c):
    if a:
        print b
    elif c:
        print 'hello'
```

I'd like to move around and edit this file using familiar vim movements.  For instance, using (, ), [[, ]], {, } or deleting/yanking/changing text using commands like di}.

In other languages (like C++, Java, C#, etc) you've got curly brackets abound, so using a movement like di} can easily find a matching curly brace and act on that block. And in fact if I am on the 'b' character on the above text and do a di) in vim, it successfully deletes the text between the two parens.

The issue is in python's detection of code blocks, I think.  Using (, ), [[, ]], {, or } as movements all pretty much do the same thing, bringing you to the start (above or on the def line) or end (after the last line of the function) of the function.  And there is no way, as far as I know, to easily tell vim "select everything for this indentation block."  In the above example, I'd like to be on in 'i' of the if line, type di} and have it delete the entire if block (to the end of this particular function).

I'm sure it should be possible to tell vim to operate on an indentation basis for such movements (well, maybe not that particular movement, but some user defined action).  Any thoughts on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 59):

#### Square Bracket Mappings `[[`, `]]`, `[m`, `]m` and similar

[`$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/python.vim`](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/ftplugin/python.vim) now (2018) remaps all builtin mappings documented under `:h ]]` and `:h ]m` for the python language. The mappings are:

```
]] Jump forward to begin of next toplevel
[[ Jump backwards to begin of current toplevel (if already there, previous toplevel)
]m Jump forward to begin of next method/scope
[m Jump backwords to begin of previous method/scope

][ Jump forward to end of current toplevel
[] Jump backward to end of previous of toplevel
]M Jump forward to end of current method/scope
[M Jump backward to end of previous method/scope
```

Following example source code with comments illustrates the different mappings

```
class Mapping:                              # [[[[
    def __init__(self, iterable):
        pass

    def update(self, iterable):
        pass

    __update = update                       # []

class Reverse:                              # [[ or [m[m
    def __init__(self, data):               # [m
        self.data = data
        self.index = len(data)              # [M

    def __iter__(self):                     # <--- CURSOR
        return self                         # ]M

    def __next__(self):                     # ]m
        if self.index == 0:
            raise StopIteration
        self.index = self.index - 1
        return self.data[self.index]        # ][

class MappingSubclass(Mapping):             # ]] or ]m]m

    def update(self, keys, values):
        pass
```

The mappings have been added and improved in the commits [abd468ed0](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/abd468ed0fbcba391e7833feeaa7de3ced841455/runtime/ftplugin/python.vim) (2016-09-08), [01164a6546b4](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/01164a6546b4c635daf96a1f17d1cb2d07f32a66/runtime/ftplugin/python.vim) (2017-11-02), and  [7f2e9d7c9cd](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/7f2e9d7c9cdfc5201a899b7b610edf64bf80c45f/runtime/ftplugin/python.vim) (2017-11-11).

If you do not have the new version of this file yet, you can download it and put it into `~/.vim/ftplugin/python.vim`. This folder takes precedence before `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin`.

Before these mappings have been added to `$VIMRUNTIME`, there has been the plugin `python-mode` which provides `[[`, `]]`, `[M`, and `]M`. In addition `python-mode` also defines the text objects `aC`, `iC`, `aM`, and `iM`:

#### Plugin [python-mode](https://github.com/python-mode/python-mode)

This vim plugin provides motions similar to built-in ones:

```
2.4 Vim motion ~
                                                                *pymode-motion*

Support Vim motion (See |operator|) for python objects (such as functions,
class and methods).

`C` — means class
`M` — means method or function
                                                            *pymode-motion-keys*

==========  ============================
Key         Command (modes)
==========  ============================
[[          Jump to previous class or function (normal, visual, operator)
]]          Jump to next class or function  (normal, visual, operator)
[M          Jump to previous class or method (normal, visual, operator)
]M          Jump to next class or method (normal, visual, operator)
aC          Select a class. Ex: vaC, daC, yaC, caC (normal, operator)
iC          Select inner class. Ex: viC, diC, yiC, ciC (normal, operator)
aM          Select a function or method. Ex: vaM, daM, yaM, caM (normal, operator)
iM          Select inner func. or method. Ex: viM, diM, yiM, ciM (normal, operator)
==========  ============================
```

#### Plugin [Pythonsense](https://github.com/jeetsukumaran/vim-pythonsense)

This plugin provides similar motions but slightly modified:

> The stock Vim 8.0 "class" motions ("]]", "[[", etc.), find blocks that begin at the first column, regardless of whether or not these are class or function blocks, while its method/function motions ("[m", "]m", etc.) find all blocks at any indent regardless of whether or not these are class or function blocks. In contrast, "Pythonsense" class motions work on finding all and only class definitions, regardless of their indent level, while its method/function motions work on finding all and only method/function definitions, regardless of their indent level.

All details and examples are given at https://github.com/jeetsukumaran/vim-pythonsense#stock-vim-vs-pythonsense-motions.
In addition, this plugin defines the text objects `ic/ac` (class), `if/af` (function), `id/ad` (docstring).

#### Neovim & [nvim-treesitter-textobjects](https://github.com/nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter-textobjects)

For neovim, you can use treesitter and the neovim plugin [nvim-treesitter-textobjects](https://github.com/nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter-textobjects#text-objects-move).

#### Textobjects `if/af` & `ic`/`ac`

These are not contained in `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/python.vim` but are provided by a few plugins

- [python-mode](https://github.com/python-mode/python-mode)
- [vim-pythonsense](https://github.com/jeetsukumaran/vim-pythonsense)
- [nvim-treesitter-textobjects (neovim-only)](https://github.com/nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter-textobjects)

For a discussion about textobjects for python see [what's the fastest way to select a function of Python via VIM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579723/whats-the-fastest-way-to-select-a-function-of-python-via-vim).

Comment: In 2016, this is the standard answer.

Comment: Hi: thanks for the answer. Just real quick: is there a way that the first method correctly deals with decorators?

Comment: @clog14 Sorry, I do not know the answer. If you mean by the first method the mappings given in `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/python.vim`, I would suggest that you raise an issue in the upstream repository under https://github.com/tpict/vim-ftplugin-python. Give an example file and a description of the behavior you expect for the different square bracket mappings.

Answer (score 21):

## [python.vim](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=30)

Makes it much easier to navigate around python code blocks.

Shortcuts:

- `]t`      -- Jump to beginning of block
- `]e`      -- Jump to end of block
- `]v`      -- Select (Visual Line Mode) block
- `]<`      -- Shift block to left
- `]>`      -- Shift block to right
- `]#`      -- Comment selection
- `]u`      -- Uncomment selection
- `]c`      -- Select current/previous class
- `]d`      -- Select current/previous function
- `]<up>`   -- Jump to previous line with the same/lower indentation
- `]<down>` -- Jump to next line with the same/lower indentation

## [python_match.vim](https://vim.sourceforge.io/scripts/script.php?script_id=386)

extends `%`:

- `%`  - cycle through if/elif/else, try/except/catch, for/continue/break
- `g%` - move opposite of `%`
- `[%` - move to the beginning of the current code block
- `]%` - move to the end of the current code block

All the above motions work with Normal, Visual, and Operator-pending modes, so:

- `d]%`  - delete until the end of the current block
- `v]%d` - should do the same, going through Visual mode so that
  you can see what is being deleted
- `V]%d` - above, but with line selection

Comment: Still available at https://web.archive.org/web/20230206092947/https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=30

Answer (score 6):

It's very easy to move indented blocks when you have `set foldmethod=indent`. For example, if you're on the `def main():` line in the following snippet:

```
def main():
+-- 35 lines: gps.init()-----------------------------------------------------

if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

then `dj` takes the whole main function and it can be pasted elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

To address your final paragraph, the following script defines a new "indent" text-object that you can perform actions on.  For instance, <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> deletes everything indented at the same level as the line the cursor is on.

See the plugin's documentation for more info: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3037