# what's the fastest way to select a function of Python via VIM?

Tags: python, vim

Is it possible without any plugins?
Or what's the best plugin for edit python file?

Comment: do you mean for code-completion, then have a look at omni-completion. Perhaps be a bit more verbose in your question...

Comment: Not sure if this is what they meant, but I read this at first as wanting to know if one can literally select a function easily (like one can use % in a language which uses braces).

Comment: You want code completion or jumping to a specified function?

Comment: The OP means to use VIM's internal select feature `v` and motions to select an entire Python (indentation-delimited) function.

Comment: Note that there is a Stack Exchange community just for Vi/Vim/Neovim now: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 15):

try `vis` to visualy select and `o` to jump edges

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if the function contains a blank line.

Comment: Some better options are provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28284564/2071807). Note particularly `]m` which seems to work fairly well.

Answer (score 10):

The way I do it is not specific to functions. It will just select a continuous block of Python code:

`v]]` if what you want to select is below the cursor
`v[[` if it is above the cursor.

Just remove one bracket if the cursor is on the first line of the code block you want to select.

Comment: Does this work by looking at indentation? Where can I read more about this in Vim's help?

Answer (score 5):

I assume you mean visually selecting the whole function quickly. One way is to use the plugin [Indent text object](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3037) ([GitHub](https://github.com/michaeljsmith/vim-indent-object)). You can use `vai` to select the whole function, provided your cursor is inside the function and only 1 indentation level lower.

If you really want select function regardless of indentation level, I suggest you read [this](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Creating_new_text_objects) and write your own text object. I imagine it would be quite easy since Python has def keyword for defining function.

Answer (score 5):

With this plugin https://github.com/bps/vim-textobj-python 
you can select, delete, change, etc:

```
af: a function
if: inner function
ac: a class
ic: inner class
```

Comment: This works on functions, but can't seem to handle classes or methods.

Answer (score 4):

I normally use `vip` or any of the above depending on the need, do not forget that you can always select up (i.e., down =)) to the next occurrence using `v/match` (followed by Enter to confirm, and possibly n for next). For python, you could look for the next `def` or for the `return` (ret is normally enough).

This isn't the fastest at the beginning, but it is very general, use it in any language and also outside coding (md, latex, etc.).

Comment: This actually works well considering people use autoformatter like black these days...

Answer (score 0):

you have to use [omnicompletion for vim7](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1542) but it's only working with vim-nox, vim-gtk, vim-gnome o vim-athen

also read throu [this page](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Vim) for configuring vim with python (autoindend, syntax highlight and autocompletion)

Answer (score 0):

I try to avoid visual, hence for actions like yank, I tend to go to the beginning of the paragraph `[[`, yank till the end `y]]` and come back `^o`.
All in one, it is `[[y]]^o` (With `^` standing for control).

For visual you might use `[[v]]` or some variations like `[[v][`, `[[v]m`, or `[[v]M`.

Answer (score 0):

If your function is long or has many blank lines, using `v}}...}}d` is pretty slow.

The quickest way I've found (without plug-ins) is `zc2dd`. The command `zc` closes the fold under the cursor, so if you are at the function declaration or any line at the outermost indent level, the whole function will fold. Then `2dd` (or `3dd` if you have two blank lines before/after your function) will remove the whole thing.