# Equivalent of shift+% brace matching in Python

Tags: python, vim, indentation

In Perl or C (using VIM as the editor) it is easier to see which part is with in the loop and what level it is nested by selecting a brace and clicking `shift+%` take you to corresponding matching brace.

What is the equivalent way to see the top and end of a block in Python?

I know indentation can visibly let you see it but with two or more screenful of multiple indents the % character brace matching equivalent will surely prevail, instead of 
verifying the column numbers.

Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [More efficient movements editing python files in vim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/896145/more-efficient-movements-editing-python-files-in-vim)