# jump to the next python class or function in vim

Tags: python, vim

I'm trying to jump to the next python class or function in vim with the following commands:

```
autocmd FileType python nnoremap <buffer> [[ ?^class|^\s*def<CR>
autocmd FileType python nnoremap <buffer> ]] /^class|^\s*def<CR>
```

But it doesn't work. Vim prompted:

```
Error detected while processing FileType Auto commands for "python":
E492: Not an editor command: ^\s*def<CR>
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Why don't use a plugin, for example, [**Python-mode**](https://github.com/klen/python-mode)? Please check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28284564/5299236).

Comment: @KevinGuan Thank you, I tried that before. It has some bugs, and I only need a small part of functionalities in it. So I think maybe I can write something that is more suitable for me :)

Comment: Why do you go through all that trouble when those mappings are *already* defined in `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/python.vim`?

Comment: @romainl But when I tried `[[` or `]]` in vim without any extra configurations, it can only jump to the previous/next class, skipping all the class methods in between.

Comment: @romainl I just leafed through `python.vim` file, and found that `[m` and `]m` worked the way as I expected. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 6):

After lots of trying, I found the following code worked. I need to add `\\` before `|`

```
autocmd FileType python nnoremap <buffer> [[ ?^class\\|^\s*def<CR>
autocmd FileType python nnoremap <buffer> ]] /^class\\|^\s*def<CR>
```

As an alternative way, I found that putting the two lines in `~/.vim/ftplugin/python.vim` is more convenient

```
nnoremap [[ ?^class\|^\s*def<CR>
nnoremap ]] /^class\|^\s*def<CR>
```

Comment: Thank you. I used the following improved regex: ``autocmd FileType python nnoremap <buffer> <C-k> ?^\s*\zs\<class\>\\|^\s*\zs\<def\><CR>`` (other one analogous, mapped to C-j)

Comment: Hi, why second code without `<buffer>`  `nnoremap [[ ?^class\|^\s*def<CR>` is not working in `.vimrc` ? I am using mostly python.

Comment: @GrzegorzKrug, the observation on changing "\" to "\\" is valid for the second form too.

Answer (score 0):

Currently a excellent option in this case is to use [vim-ftplugin-python](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/blob/master/runtime/ftplugin/python.vim) available in official nvim/vim repo:

In this [line](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/blob/481a3158866638946c91fab28ae5bca97ff1e814/runtime/ftplugin/python.vim#L58) we have the related maps:

```
let b:next_toplevel='\v%$\|^(class\|def\|async def)>'
let b:prev_toplevel='\v^(class\|def\|async def)>'
let b:next_endtoplevel='\v%$\|\S.*\n+(def\|class)'
let b:prev_endtoplevel='\v\S.*\n+(def\|class)'
let b:next='\v%$\|^\s*(class\|def\|async def)>'
let b:prev='\v^\s*(class\|def\|async def)>'
let b:next_end='\v\S\n*(%$\|^(\s*\n*)*(class\|def\|async def)\|^\S)'
let b:prev_end='\v\S\n*(^(\s*\n*)*(class\|def\|async def)\|^\S)'

if !exists('g:no_plugin_maps') && !exists('g:no_python_maps')
    execute "nnoremap <silent> <buffer> ]] :call <SID>Python_jump('n', '". b:next_toplevel."', 'W', v:count1)<cr>"
    execute "nnoremap <silent> <buffer> [[ :call <SID>Python_jump('n', '". b:prev_toplevel."', 'Wb', v:count1)<cr>"
    execute "nnoremap <silent> <buffer> ][ :call <SID>Python_jump('n', '". b:next_endtoplevel."', 'W', v:count1, 0)<cr>"
    execute "nnoremap <silent> <buffer> [] :call <SID>Python_jump('n', '". b:prev_endtoplevel."', 'Wb', v:count1, 0)<cr>"
    execute "nnoremap <silent> <buffer> ]m :call <SID>Python_jump('n', '". b:next."', 'W', v:count1)<cr>"
    execute "nnoremap <silent> <buffer> [m :call <SID>Python_jump('n', '". b:prev."', 'Wb', v:count1)<cr>"
    execute "nnoremap <silent> <buffer> ]M :call <SID>Python_jump('n', '". b:next_end."', 'W', v:count1, 0)<cr>"
    execute "nnoremap <silent> <buffer> [M :call <SID>Python_jump('n', '". b:prev_end."', 'Wb', v:count1, 0)<cr>"

    execute "onoremap <silent> <buffer> ]] :call <SID>Python_jump('o', '". b:next_toplevel."', 'W', v:count1)<cr>"
    execute "onoremap <silent> <buffer> [[ :call <SID>Python_jump('o', '". b:prev_toplevel."', 'Wb', v:count1)<cr>"
    execute "onoremap <silent> <buffer> ][ :call <SID>Python_jump('o', '". b:next_endtoplevel."', 'W', v:count1, 0)<cr>"
    execute "onoremap <silent> <buffer> [] :call <SID>Python_jump('o', '". b:prev_endtoplevel."', 'Wb', v:count1, 0)<cr>"
    execute "onoremap <silent> <buffer> ]m :call <SID>Python_jump('o', '". b:next."', 'W', v:count1)<cr>"
    execute "onoremap <silent> <buffer> [m :call <SID>Python_jump('o', '". b:prev."', 'Wb', v:count1)<cr>"
    execute "onoremap <silent> <buffer> ]M :call <SID>Python_jump('o', '". b:next_end."', 'W', v:count1, 0)<cr>"
    execute "onoremap <silent> <buffer> [M :call <SID>Python_jump('o', '". b:prev_end."', 'Wb', v:count1, 0)<cr>"

    execute "xnoremap <silent> <buffer> ]] :call <SID>Python_jump('x', '". b:next_toplevel."', 'W', v:count1)<cr>"
    execute "xnoremap <silent> <buffer> [[ :call <SID>Python_jump('x', '". b:prev_toplevel."', 'Wb', v:count1)<cr>"
    execute "xnoremap <silent> <buffer> ][ :call <SID>Python_jump('x', '". b:next_endtoplevel."', 'W', v:count1, 0)<cr>"
    execute "xnoremap <silent> <buffer> [] :call <SID>Python_jump('x', '". b:prev_endtoplevel."', 'Wb', v:count1, 0)<cr>"
    execute "xnoremap <silent> <buffer> ]m :call <SID>Python_jump('x', '". b:next."', 'W', v:count1)<cr>"
    execute "xnoremap <silent> <buffer> [m :call <SID>Python_jump('x', '". b:prev."', 'Wb', v:count1)<cr>"
    execute "xnoremap <silent> <buffer> ]M :call <SID>Python_jump('x', '". b:next_end."', 'W', v:count1, 0)<cr>"
    execute "xnoremap <silent> <buffer> [M :call <SID>Python_jump('x', '". b:prev_end."', 'Wb', v:count1, 0)<cr>"
endif
```